# java thread - threads in dual processor system

Tags: multithreading

We all know that in a system only one thread at a time can be executed. Is it possible in java to execute two thread at the same time if the system is having dual processors?

Comment: Please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061707/1047582

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java multithreading in a laptop having quad-core processor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059801/java-multithreading-in-a-laptop-having-quad-core-processor)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on `JVM`. If you use many Java `Thread` then will be executed on one of your processor. ( At the same time - it depends on timing - you need to know that your 2 threads are not alone in your machine.